Is this a property of continuous ordinal-length sequences?
Fix a [countable?] limit ordinal $\gamma$, a compact* Hausdorff space $X$, and a continuous function $s:\gamma\to X$. Let $\sigma$ be the restriction of $s$ to $\gamma\setminus\gamma'$ (the set of successor ordinals less than $\gamma$), and suppose that $\lim_{\alpha\to\gamma}\sigma(\alpha)=x$ for some $x\in X$. Does it follow that $\lim_{\alpha\to\gamma}s(\alpha)=x$?
* Technically $X$ itself doesn't need to be compact, but we want to have a meaningful notion of  "the" compactification of $X$ to make sure that the limit is uniquely defined.

If $X$ is compact then I think it is true since $X$ will also be regular.
If $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow \gamma}s(\alpha)\neq x$ then we would need that the limit ordinals under $\gamma$ must be cofinal and there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that all $s$ sends all of the limit ordinals outside of $U$. By regularity we have that there exists an open set $V$ such that $x\in V\subseteq \overline{V}\subseteq U$. We have by definition of limit that there exists a $\beta<\gamma$ such that for all $\alpha>\beta$ we have $\sigma(\alpha')\in V$. In particular by continuity of $s$ this means that all for all $\alpha>\beta$ $s(\alpha)\in \overline{V}\subseteq U$ which is a contradiction.
If $X$ is not regular I believe this is false. Take the $K$ topology on $\mathbb{R}$, that is we extend the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ to allow $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\frac{1}{n+1}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ to be open. This space will be $T_2$ but will not be regular. Now take any continuous strictly decreasing function  $s:\omega^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $\omega\cdot n\mapsto \frac{1}{n+1}$. That is we have that for all $n$, the the sequence $(s(\omega\cdot n+m))_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ is contained in the interval $[\frac{1}{n+2},\frac{1}{n+1}]$ and is strictly decreasing and convergent to $\frac{1}{n+2}$. You have that in this case $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\omega^2}\sigma(\alpha)=0$ however $s$ does not converge to $0$ since all of the limit points are outside of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\frac{1}{n+1}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ which is an open neighborhood of $0$.
Edit: This should generalize for any ordinal $\gamma$ whose limit ordinals are cofinal. Instead of taking $\mathbb{R}$ with the $K$ topology you would probably need to get an appropriate $\aleph_\alpha=|\gamma|$ saturated linear order, take its Dedekind completion $L$ with its order topology. Using transfinite recursion define a continuous strictly decreasing sequence $s:\gamma\rightarrow L$ which converges to some point $x$ and add to the topology of $L$ the open set $L\setminus\{s(\beta): \beta<\gamma \text{ limit ordinal}\}$.
